# Vue JS: API call request on app.vue in single page application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my project i'm suffering from delay in API requests and that's because i have huge amount of data in API, so i added a **cache** but it still appears white page when page creates, **so i was thinking of adding API call on app.vue so request will be faster**... is there a way to do it?
now i'm making API request on each page in my project
code below:

```html
//building.vue where buildings api used

<template>
    <b-row class="icon-examples">
              
             
              <b-col lg="3" md="6"  v-for="(building, index) in buildings"
              :key="index" >
                
                <button type="button" class="btn-icon-clipboard" @click="GoToBuilding(building._id)"
      >
                  <div>
                    <i class="ni ni-building"></i>
                <router-link
                  class="question-routerToDetail"
                  :to="`/tables/${building._id}`"
                >      <span > B info - </span>
                    <span>{{building.building_number}}</span></router-link>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </b-col>
         

            </b-row>
</template>

<script>
import BuildingsService from "../../../services/ApiService"
export default {

    data() {
        return {
  

   
        };
    },
    components: {
      props:
  ['buildings'],
       
      BaseHeader,
      //  buildings:[]
    },
 

    }
}
</script>
```

`app.vue`:

```html
<template>
  
<router-view :number="count" @send="getNewCount"   @reset="onReset" :buildings="buildings">

<sidebar :number="count" @reset="onReset"/>

</router-view>
</template>
<script>

export default {
components: {
    sidebar,

  },
    data() {
        return {
         buildings: []
      };
        
    },
         
    created(){
    BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
                this.buildings = response.data.response;
                 console.log(this.buildings , "skk")
            });

          }
}
</script>
```

can i add saved API request array in app.vue and use it on other pages? and is it gonna improve my API call?

thanks in advance

Edit: updated question depending on answer below.. but getting empty data with no console errors

Comment: Of course, a cache will speed up requests after the first one, but offers no help on the first one (and no help whenever the cache goes out of date).  I'd think of this as a UX problem: does user really need all that data at once?  If not, get less.  If they do need it, then they'll have to wait for the cache to refresh.  It's your UI's job to tell user that your app is busy fetching the data they need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the API a single time in the component that contains `router-view` and pass down the results to rendered components through props. The rendered components must declare the `props` that will be passed down to them, but only if they will be using it.

```
<template>
    <router-view :number="count" 
        @send="getNewCount" @reset="onReset"
        :buildings="buildings">
        <sidebar :number="count" @reset="onReset"/>
    </router-view>
</template>
<script>
    import BuildingsService from "../../../services/ApiService"
    export default {
        components: {
            sidebar,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                buildings: []
            };
        },
        created(){ 
            BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
                this.buildings = response.data.response;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

But if the API call returns a huge amount of data or is really slow, then I really suggest that you check into optimizing the backend queries of your API, paginating results, and loading them progressively with lazy load on scroll or something.

Also it would be good if you can keep something in your state to check if the data is being loaded or not, so that you can show a loader or something rather than a white page until you get the results.

Comment: i added your code in app.vue, and i defiened `buildings` as a prop in the page where i use this api but i'm getting empty white page with zero console error

Comment: i updated my question depending on your answer, please take a look

Comment: `props` should be in the component/page that gets the passed data from app.vue, and not inside the component on app.vue. So it should be in buildings.vue. And also app.vue should have local data `buildings` to hold it for all child components, if that's the way you are going.

Comment: i'm gettinh `Property or method "buildings" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`  :\

Comment: Yeah that's what I have mentioned, you should give `data() { return { buildings: []} }` in app.vue.

Comment: And inside buildings.vue you should defined the prop `props: ['buildings']`.

Comment: sorry i fixed that.. but still white page appears with no console errors ... i updated my question again please take alook

Comment: Can you provide more info on where  the `Building` in `{Building.building_number}`  comes from in building.vue ?

Comment: i simplified code above for you to understand ... now i'm looping over `buildings` in building.vue but still no data coming from api

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to adapt getBuildings(), such that it will call the backend only once and store the result in a property of BuildingsService, e.g. `cachedBuildings`.

If cachedBuildings is empty, getBuildings() calls the backend and stores the result in cachedBuildings.

If cachedBuildings is not empty, getBuildings() returns cachedBuildings.

The advantage of this solution is, that you only adapt your code in one place and the caching is transparent for every component.